# Jenkins Pipeline passing parameter as shell script argument

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a parameterized Jenkins Pipeline with a default value and I'm trying to pass that param as a script argument but it doesn't seem to pass anything. Here is the script :

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Building') {
         steps {
            build job: 'myProject', parameters: [string(name: 'configuration', value: '${configuration}')]
         }
      }
      stage('Doing stuff') {
          steps {
            sh "~/scripts/myScript ${configuration}"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

It seems to work for the build step but not for the script. I returns an error saying I have no argument.
I tried to get it with `${configuration}`, `${params.configuration}` and `$configuration`.

What is the right way to access a param and pass it correctly to a script ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are using the build step, to pass a parameter to the Jenkins job 'myProject'.

```
build job: 'myProject', parameters: [string(name: 'configuration', value: '${configuration}')]
```

If you want to declare a Parameter in this job you need to declare your parameter in a "parameters" block.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  parameters {
    string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'configuration')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Doing stuff') {
        steps {
            sh "~/scripts/myScript ${configuration}"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I add the `parameters` block when I checked the "This project is parameterized" checkbox ? Isn't that the same thing ?

Comment: Yes it is actually, my bad Im used to declare them in my pipeline, forgot the configuration menu...